# The compiler ignores my else statement

Tags: c

i'm making a game of life in C. I'm checking if a cell is alive (using a typedef of DEAD or ALIVE called state) and then check things about its neighbours. and if it's dead, I'm checking if it should live next generation.
Problem is it doesn't work, when I debug the program in gdb, it seems to ignore my else statement.
This is the relevant part of my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define maxHeight 10
#define maxWidth 10
#define maxGenerations 100
typedef enum { DEAD, ALIVE } state;
void nextGeneration(state[][maxHeight][maxWidth], int, int, int);
int numberOfNeighbours(state[][maxHeight][maxWidth], int, int, int);
void printGeneration(state[][maxHeight][maxWidth], int, int, int);
void nextGeneration(state board[][maxHeight][maxWidth], int requestedGeneration, int boardHeight, int boardWidth)
{
        int h;
        int w;
        int currentNumOfNeighbours;
        for(h = 0; h < boardHeight; h++)
                for(w = 0; w < boardHeight; w++)
                {
                        currentNumOfNeighbours = numberOfNeighbours(board, requestedGeneration, h, w);
                        if(board[requestedGeneration][h][w] == ALIVE)
                        {
                                if(currentNumOfNeighbours == 2 || currentNumOfNeighbours == 3)
                                {
                                        board[requestedGeneration - 1][h][w] == ALIVE;
                                }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                                if(currentNumOfNeighbours == 3)
                                        board[requestedGeneration - 1][h][w] == ALIVE;
                        }
                }
}
```

Can you tell me what's wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: probably because the first statement is true so it won't hit the else

Comment: Please reduce your code to a subset, so we can see better what's your problem is.

Comment: But it doesn't go into the true statement either.

Comment: It goes into the if statement before, otherwise it should execute the else statement. However, it's not guaranteed to enter the sub-if statement, causing it to execute nothing... ;)

Answer (score 6):

If you are compiling with optimizations, the compiler will probably optimize that away by completely removing it from the output:

```
if(currentNumOfNeighbours == 3)
    board[requestedGeneration - 1][h][w] == ALIVE;
```

...because it has no actual effect. You probably meant:

```
if(currentNumOfNeighbours == 3)
    board[requestedGeneration - 1][h][w] = ALIVE;
```

...using assignment (`=`) instead of comparison (`==`). Even if it doesn't take it out, it doesn't actually do anything.